# How to deserialise or format WebAPI result into specific json structure

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I was working with a .net core 3.1 Web API. Which is getting data from an external API. Following is my code Controller  part

```
[HttpGet("transinfo/{id}")]        
public Object GettransactionData(int id)
{
  var result=_transaction.GettransactionDetails(id).Result;
  List<PipeLineResponse> P = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PipeLineResponse>>(result.ToString());
  PipeLineResponseObject P1 = new PipeLineResponseObject();
  P1.data = P;
  return P1;
}
```

And my service code as follows

```
public async Task<Object> GettransactionDetails(int id)
{
  string request=//fetched from db 
  var stringContent = new StringContent(request);            
  Client = utilities.GetHttpClient();
  string apiEndpoint=//External API URL
  HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await Client.PostAsync(apiEndpoint, stringContent);
  if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
      return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<Object>();     
  }
}
```

But i am getting the result in following format (response from postman)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Tranid": "34540d40-7db8-44c1-9a2a-5072c2d01756",
      "fields": {
        "Fields.10": "1001",
        "Fields.11": "Test1",
        "Fields.12": "Fixed1"
      }
    },
    {
      "Tranid": "145800f9-c4a5-4625-84d7-29af5e674a14",
      "fields": {
        "Fields.10": "1002",
        "Fields.11": "Test2",
        "Fields.12": "Fixed2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But i need the data in following format

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "TransactionID": "34540d40-7db8-44c1-9a2a-5072c2d01756",
      "fieldsList": [
        {
          "fieldId": "10",
          "fieldValue": "1001"
        },
        {
          "fieldId": "11",
          "fieldValue": "Test1"
        },
        {
          "fieldId": "12",
          "fieldValue": "Fixed1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "TransactionID": "145800f9-c4a5-4625-84d7-29af5e674a14",
      "fieldsList": [
        {
          "fieldId": "10",
          "fieldValue": "1002"
        },
        {
          "fieldId": "11",
          "fieldValue": "Test2"
        },
        {
          "fieldId": "12",
          "fieldValue": "Fixed2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i achieve this ? is possible to deserialise using JObject or JArray? Please help.
i have tried to create following model class and tried to deserialise but not getting result as expected.

```
public class PipeLineResponse
{
   public string TransactionID { get; set; }
   public List<Dictionary<string, string>> fields { get; set; }
}    

public class PipeLineResponseObject
{
 public List<PipeLineResponse> data { get; set; }
}
```

How to create that json in that format any DTO or Automapper will work ? Please help me with samples.

Comment: You can achieve that using custom parsing of the json string. But however, a cleaner approach can be creating a ViewModel of the required structure (for your case, you can have a class with a property `data` of type `IEnumerable<T>` and `T` is the type of the inner object), map the response from service to your viewmodel and let the the default serialization take over from there.

Comment: @SaiGummaluri : i have tried after creating class models but getting error confused on how to create that

Comment: The structure you are looking at does not seem complicated. What error are you running into?

Comment: @SaiGummaluri i will add those models i have created not sure this will work or not

Comment: @Maximilian Ast

Comment: Try this https://json2csharp.com/, just paste your json and it will give you class structure

Comment: @AcAnanth - The response from the service you are calling actually returns `fields` as one single object in which all the fields are bundled together. However, your required structure has an array of individual fields. You are getting an error because of this difference. A way out can be to capture your response into an intermediate `DTO` (this can be the structure you're getting using `json2csharp`). Map this DTO to ViewModel either manually or using something like `AutoMapper`. The requirement you're looking at is totally doable.

Comment: @AcAnanth - Alternatively, if you do not want to take the DTO route, you can leverage `Newtonsoft.Json` and use `LINQ To JSON`: Parse the response from service and map it to the ViewModel manually. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: @SaiGummaluri : i am very new to those concepts. Can you help me out?

Comment: @AcAnanth - Sure, will come up with some sample code in some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that I am laying down here takes the `DTO` approach. The response from the service is being deserialized to the DTO, which further is being manually mapped to the final `ViewModel` that we are sending to the client. *By no means, this implementation is production-ready and there is scope for improvement, for which I am adding in comments. But this gives a detailed understanding of how we can handle these kind of scenarios.* We are making use of `Newtonsoft.Json`, which can be pulled into your project via the `NuGet` package manager.

#### Structure of the `DTO`

```
// RootDTO.cs
// This structure is directly based on the response obtained from remote service.

public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="Fields.10")]
    public string Fields10 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Fields.11")]
    public string Fields11 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Fields.12")]
    public string Fields12 { get; set; } 
}

public class Datum
{
    public string Tranid { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class RootDTO
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="data")]
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

#### Structure of `ViewModel`

```
// PipelineResponse.cs
public class FieldsList
{
    public string fieldId { get; set; }
    public string fieldValue { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseDatum
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "TransactionID")]
    public string TransactionID { get; set; }
    public List<FieldsList> fieldsList { get; set; }
}
   
public class PipelineResponse
{        
    public List<ResponseDatum> data { get; set; }
}
```

#### Deserializing the response to the `DTO`

```
// ...other code
var responseString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<Object>();
// This is where the DTO object is created. This should be mapped to view model type.
var responseDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootDTO>(responseString);
```

#### Mapping the `DTO` to `ViewModel`

The mapping from DTO type to ViewModel type needs to be done before sending the response to the client. It is the view model type that is sent to the client. This logic can be placed within a separate helper (ideally, to separate concerns) or any other location as per the practices you are following.

```
public PipelineResponse ConvertResponseDTOToResponse(RootDTO responseDTO)
{
    // FieldId is being hardcoded here. Instead, you can use Reflection to 
    // fetch the property name, split on '.' and take the item at index 1.
    // Notice that DTO properties have "JsonProperty" attributes for this.
    try
    {        
        List<ResponseDatum> responseList = new List<ResponseDatum>();
        if (responseDTO != null)
        {
            // Reflection can be used to avoid hardcoding on 'fieldId'
            foreach (var item in responseDTO.data)
            {
                var responseDataObj = new ResponseDatum
                {
                    TransactionID = item.Tranid,
                    fieldsList = new List<FieldsList>
                    {
                        new FieldsList
                        {
                            fieldValue = item.fields.Fields10,
                            fieldId = "10"
                        },
                        new FieldsList
                        {
                            fieldValue = item.fields.Fields11,
                            fieldId = "11"
                        },
                        new FieldsList
                        {
                            fieldValue = item.fields.Fields12,
                            fieldId = "12"
                        }
                    }
                };
                responseList.Add(responseDataObj);
            }
        }

        // This object is what you return from your controller endpoint finally.
        // The serialized response of this object is of the json structure you need 
        return new PipelineResponse { data = responseList };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. public class Fields this one is hardcoded with 10,11 and 12 right? that my change in my case , no.of  fields may change. Is there a dynamic way to handle that?

Comment: @AcAnanth - If you want to handle varying json structures, you can do that by creating a custom `JsonConverter` (We are using the default JsonConverter in the above implementation). Mapping is going to use `reflection` like I mentioned in the comments in the answer. Take a look at this and let me know if you need further help! https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/deserialize-different-json-object-same-class/

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. It really helped